# Contextual Binding with Spring.net

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, spring.net

In other IoC containers like [ninject](http://dojo.ninject.org/Contextual%20Binding.ashx) you can setup contextual binding pretty easily. I was wondering if contextual binding was supported by the Spring.net IoC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use Spring Expressions to do contextual binding. Instead of

```
<object name="myotherobject" ... />

<object name="thisobject">
  <property name="TheService" ref="myotherobject" />
```

you may write

```
<property name="TheService" expr="<whatever spring expression you like>" />
```

cheers,
Erich